# Return values from wix custom-action dll

Tags: windows, dll, wix, custom-action

I have a .dll I'm using inside a wix-built .msi that is currently returning Windows error codes upon failure. [This page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx) seems to imply that I can only use the values listed with dll executables.

The calls are failing (returning non-zero values), but no error message is given to the user.  Do I need to modify my .dll to use the "accepted" return values for this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.